# Does the properness of 'Street' (in the name of a street) survive when discussing two particular streets together?

Tags: proper-nouns

So do Smith St and Wesson St meet:

- "at the corner of Smith & Wesson Streets";  or
- "at the corner of Smith & Wesson streets"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **British English,** it does survive. In fact, the properness of *Street* generally precludes the treatment you propose.

> An accident at the junction of Queen Elizabeth Street and Tooley Street.

One might possibly hear “Queen Elizabeth and Tooley Streets,” perhaps in a radio traffic report, but since that’s spoken any capitalisation is unclear. We don’t **write** it that way.

Comment: Ditto in the US

Comment: @bib Is "At the corner of Smith & Wesson" acceptable in the OP's case? British English doesn't do that at all.

Comment: Using *Streets* would be fine. Often the proper names are used and the *Street* or *Avenue* is simple dropped, as in *the intersection of Hollywood and Vine.*