# Singular or Plural after a List of Streets using "or"?

Tags: grammatical-number, lists

When writing a list of streets using "and", I can obviously pluralize.

> The event will take place on Maple, Walnut, and Orange Streets.

When using "or", however, which is correct/best?

- The event will take place on Maple, Walnut, **or** Orange **Streets**.
- The event will take place on Maple, Walnut, **or** Orange **Street**.
- The event will take place on Maple **St**, Walnut **St**, **or** Orange **St**.

Comment: Actually the "obvious plural" is [not obvious at all](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154361).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the confusion is in the proper titles.

Orange Street is a title.

Orange St. is a title.

There is no plural of the title.

Therefore, while it is vernacular to use "Maple, Walnut, or Orange Streets," the proper phrase is:

**"...Maple Street, Walnut Street, [and][or] Orange Street."**